# Magento2 JS and CSS versioning with Search console 404 issue

Tags: magento2, seo

We are getting 404 error in Google search console regarding CSS and JS versioning.

[image]

I already blocked static folder via robots but still, after every deployment of website google search console are mentions old URL as 404.

so, if anyone know how to resolve this error?

Thanks,